Handle in-app purchase upgrades with price difference
I'm building an app using ReactNative, so I can use subscriptions inside my app, and there are three different subscriptions, A, B, and C, depending on the price.
I know that the existing IOS upgrade method is to cancel the existing subscription pro-rated to the date and then pay for the new subscription.
But due to the nature of my app, when I upgrade from B subscription to C subscription.
I want to keep the subscription period the same and only charge C-B. Is there any way?
I can specifically find out how to manage your subscription periods on a custom server without prorating them.

If your subscriptions are in the same subscription group but have different service tiers (1 is the "highest") then the App Store will do one of two things when a user changes during a subscription period:

If the move is to a higher tier then the existing subscription is cancelled and a pro-rated refund is issued.  The new subscription is charged with the new renewal date as "today".
If the move is to a lower tier then the current subscription continues until the renewal date, at which time it renews at the lower tier.
If the subscriptions are at the same tier then the current subscription continues until the renewal date, at which time the subscription will renew with the new product id.

You cannot change this behaviour.

Thank you for your response.
What happens if the subscriptions are in the same tier and have different prices?

It is the same as the third case in my answer. The price means nothing. Only the service tier matters

So unfortunately there's no way to make them only pay the difference in price when upgrading their subscription?

No, you can't have them pay a pro-rated price (ie pay the higher price for the remaining period of their current subscription).  They either complete their current period (downgrade, cross-grade) or start a new period (upgrade).
